# Properly aligned inline equations within multicols environment

Tags: multicol, alignment

Consider for instance

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1+i\\2i&3
\end{bmatrix}$.
\item $U=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1+i&1+i\\1-i&-1+i
\end{bmatrix}$.
\item $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&i\\-i&2\end{bmatrix}$.
\item $A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1-i&0\\1+i&0&0\\0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

How can I center-aligned the different items?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Hi. Thanks for the comment. I found a solution using the package 'task'. I will post it later.

Comment: Do you want vertical alignment or horizontal centering?

Answer (score 1):

You can put each formula in  a `\makebox[\linewidth]`, which will its content centred by default in the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1+i\\2i&3
\end{bmatrix}$.}
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$U=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1+i&1+i\\1-i&-1+i
\end{bmatrix}$.}
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&i\\-i&2\end{bmatrix}$.}
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1-i&0\\1+i&0&0\\0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

\end{document}
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to employ a `multicols` environment here. Typographically/visually speaking, what's really important is to position the enumerated items in such a way that the three whitespace gaps between the four items all have the same widths. This may be achieved easily by placing the four items, hand-enumerated, in a `center` environment and using `\hfill` directives to separate the items. Next, I think that the matrices in items 2 and 3 would look better if the columns were right-aligned instead of centered; this may be achieved by employing `bmatrix*` environments, which are provided by the `mathtools` package. (The `mathtools` package is a superset of the `amsmath` pacakage.) Finally, I can see no need or reason for terminating each item with a `.` ("period", aka "full stop").

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' env.
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
1.\quad $A=\begin{bmatrix}
              1&1+i\\2i&3
           \end{bmatrix}$
\hfill
2.\quad $U=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
                         1+i&1+i\\1-i&-1+i
                      \end{bmatrix*}$
\hfill
3.\quad $A=\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
             1&i\\-i&2
           \end{bmatrix*}$
\hfill
4.\quad $A=\begin{bmatrix}
                  0&1-i&0\\1+i&0&0\\0&0&1
           \end{bmatrix}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `enumitem` with its `inline` option; setting `itemjoin=\hfill` will distribute the items on the line, with equal spaces between items (provided they fit in a single line).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\hfill]
\item $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1+i\\2i&3
\end{bmatrix}$.
\item $U=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1+i&1+i\\1-i&-1+i
\end{bmatrix}$.
\item $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&i\\-i&2\end{bmatrix}$.
\item $A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1-i&0\\1+i&0&0\\0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$.
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]